# How to integrate vert.x and quartz JDBCstore

Tags: quartz-scheduler, vert.x

Can someone help me to integrate vert.x and quartz scheduler,I am aware of i can use vert.x timers but for production ready scheduler i want to store My job in database so i can reschedule those job.Any help would be highly appriciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://github.com/diabolicallabs/vertx-cron

Comment: Yes currently i am using it But i am thinking of storing Jobs in Database,coz  it will give more flexibility.

Comment: Ok, `vertx-cron` doesn't support storing jobs or triggers in a database. You need to implement this by yourself.

Comment: You can take a look at vertx [jdbc-examples](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/jdbc-examples).